# How to override contrib or core module plugin in custom module of Drupal 8

Tags: plugins, drupal

I am facing problem in overriding workbench moderation module plugin in my own custom module for administrator node edit pages of Drupal 8.4.3. Can anyone have knowledge of overriding contrib/core module plugin in custom module of Drupal 8.4.3.

Answer (score 2):

I had this type of issue using aggregator (core Drupal 8). 
I had to override/improve the default behavior.

Going deeper in the analyse of this module, I just saw that it does Plugin management and offers a hook api. 
For example I managed to make aggregator deal with enclose url image. 
Their are several ways to do it with Drupal 8. I used a very simple one : **Annotation**.

```
/**
 * Defines a default parser implementation.
 *
 * Parses RSS, Atom and RDF feeds.
 *
 * @AggregatorParser(
 *   id = "xxxxx_aggregator",
 *   title = @Translation("XXXX parser"),
 *   description = @Translation("Custom parser for RSS enclosure tag.")
 * )
 */
class CustomParser extends DefaultParser {

  /**
   * Override default parser to add the enclosure attribute to feed item
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function parse(FeedInterface $feed) {

    parent::parse($feed);
    // your code...
  }

}
```

In this given example, using `@AggregatorParser`, I allow Aggregator to detect and use another **PARSER**, my custom, which is extending the aggregator's default.

Do not forget to add it in the correct needed path. Here its : `namespace Drupal\xxxxx_aggregator\Plugin\aggregator\parser;`

Even if plugin management offers a simple way to add custom plugins and functionalities, you can also overriding the module service for deeper and more global updates.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services
https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_decoration.html

Answer (score 0):

I am managed to solve this issue by using hook_local_task_alter() in a custom module.

Answer (score -2):

You can try patching it and then using composer patches.

https://www.drupal.org/patch
https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches